# JTable scroll bar top right corner

Tags: java, swing

I have a `JTable`. When scroll bars displayed there is an empty space on the top right as in the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Is there a way to make it like in the following screenshot?

[image: Screenshot 2]

Comment: Short answer is, not, not really - because the contained view (ie the table) is contained within the scroll view and inset by the scroll bars

Comment: You can [put your own component into the corner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html#setCorner-java.lang.String-java.awt.Component-) which is more useful than expanding a column header over something that isn’t a column. I always found something useful for that corner, e.g. a button opening a popup menu, a “select all” action, a loading status icon, etc.